# How to get around CSS error of of expanding padding on hover JSX and React

Tags: css, reactjs, transition, padding

I'm making a button that I'd like to expand when hovered, as such I increase it's padding. The problem is that in both Safari and Chrome (the only browsers I've tested in) the CSS padding transition can get very confused when I place my mouse on a corner about whether I'm hovering it and alternates rapidly between hovering and not which causes it to look really bad and is unacceptable on a site. Interestingly, when testing with basic HTML/CSS with Stack Snippets or on JSFiddle I can't replicate this glitch. The CSS works perfectly with that and we don't have the non-deterministic behaviour where the program seemingly alternates between the hover and non-hover states. It's just with JSX and React that this happens.

[image: gif of bug]

```
.copy-icon {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out, padding 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.copy-icon:hover {
  background-color: #e3e1ea;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```
<span className="copy-icon">
  <span className="citation-button">
    <CopyIcon height="16" width="16" />
  </span>
  <span className="helper-text">copy</span>
</span>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So it seems that if I increase the initial horizontal padding then that lessens the probability of this glitch (i.e. I have to be more precise and deliberate with my mouse to trigger it). Though I don't want to do that necessarily if I don't have to, because this code works fine with CSS and HTML, it's just with JSX and React that I'm having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following code.

This is how I would set up an animation like the one you are trying to achieve and I don't run into the same issue you are having:

```css
.copy-icon {
  display: inline-block;
   
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
   
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
   
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.copy-icon:hover {
  background-color: #e3e1ea;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="copy-icon">
  <!--<span class="citation-button">
    <CopyIcon height="16" width="16" />
  </span>-->
  <span class="helper-text">copy</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've realized that I can't reproduce this glitch on StackOverflow. It just happens in React. When I use my or your code with basic HTML/CSS, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.
Apply hover on the containing element(citation-button) which will stop this issue.

```
<span className="copy-icon">
  <span className="citation-button">
    <CopyIcon height="16" width="16" />
  </span>
  <span className="helper-text">copy</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.copy-icon{
    height:70px;
    width: 100px; 
    background:red;
  }


.citation-button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out, padding 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.citation-button:hover {
  background-color: #e3e1ea;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

Comment: This would change the behaviour. Also the user would hover but the hovered element's position would move away from where they hovered, which is not desirable.